# The property defined in schema in mongodb is not showing hisOwnProperty in nodes

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My user schema is

```
    var mongoose    =   require('mongoose');
    var userSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
          firstName     : String,
          lastName      : String,
          ...
    })

    module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema,'user');
```

My find query on user DB

```
User.findById(userId,function(error,user){
    if(!error){
       console.log(user) //correctly print user schema as described above with _id
       for (var key in user) {
          if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log("key ", key); //not print firstName, lastName
          }
       }
    }
})
```

The for in loop doesn't work as excepted, it prints different properties which is not in schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the returned `user` is a `mongoose` `model`. It has some other properties build it in it's prototype.

If you want to iterate over the user properties, you need to do this:

```
   console.log(user)
   var objUser = user.toObject();
   for (var key in objUser) {
      if (objUser.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log("key ", key);
      }
   }
```

The `toObject()` function will turn your mongoose model into a pure Javascript object.
But, if you do this, you need to remember that mongoose model functions won't work on the pure object (because it is not a mongoose model anymore). So if you still need to use them, you need to keep a reference to the original user model.